# Easy way to enable/disable assert statements in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert

I am using the assert module in node.js 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert

In C/C++, one can easily enable/disable assert statements with macros. Can the same thing be done for node.js and javascript in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [the package](https://github.com/defunctzombie/commonjs-assert/blob/master/assert.js) you are using is adding asserts as a module and are therefor [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill).

You can simply overwrite -part- of the Object to disable the polyfill.

**Example:**
Let's say that you want to disable the `deepEqual` assert that currently looks like this:

```
assert.deepEqual = function deepEqual(actual, expected, message) {
  if (!_deepEqual(actual, expected)) {
    fail(actual, expected, message, 'deepEqual', assert.deepEqual);
  }
};
```

You can simply overwrite it by doing something like:

```
assert.deepEqual = function deepEqual(actual, expected, message) {
  // disable
};
```

**FYI**:
Assert statements are in progress: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:assert

Answer (score 3):

Here are some solutions:

**1. Test a global variable before every call**

```
const devMode = false; // or var, if you use older javascript version

devMode && assert(...);
```

This works in many cases as desired, but not when you use `assert` with side-effects, like here:

```
devMode && assert(value++, 'Value should not have been 0');
devMode && assert(myfunc(), 'myfunc unexpectedly returned false');
devMode && assert.throws(function() {
    home = '/home';
    throw new Error("Wrong value");
}, Error);
```

In above constructs, the arguments of the assert calls are not evaluated when not in `devMode`. So `value` will not be incremented, `myfunc` will not be called, and `home` will not be set.

If you use such constructs, look at the second solution:

**2. Create a mock `assert`**

In this solution you create a library with the same interface as `assert` and include either the real library or your mock library:

Your library could look like this:

```
var assert = function (value, message) {
    return true;
}
assert.ok = assert;
assert.fail = assert;
assert.equal = assert;
assert.notEqual = assert;
assert.deepEqual = assert;
assert.notDeepEqual = assert;
assert.strictEqual = assert;
assert.notStrictEqual = assert;
assert.ifError = assert;
// assert.throws should only be used to confirm that certain code will produce
// an error, but it should not change any state outside the function's scope.
// This mock version will NOT execute any of the functions passed to it.
assert.throws = assert;
// For assert.doesNotThrow the same choice is made:
assert.doesNotThrow = assert;
```

With this solution the arguments passed are evaluated, but this might still not be enough in case you pass function references, as is the case with `assert.throws` and `assert.doesNotThrow`. So you might want to implement the mock version differently, so that it does execute the function passed as first and/or second argument, even in production mode.

**3. Parse your code for production**

With this solution your aim is to remove any references to `assert` from your code. In case you only use assert calls as statements, not as part of an expression, and if there are no side-effects you depend on (see above), then make sure these assert statements are each on a separate line, and use a simple `grep` to remove these lines.

I will not elaborate in this direction, but you could make this parser more intelligent, and (by using regular expressions) let it unwrap expressions from their `assert` context. Such parser would replace:

```
 assert(value++, 'Value should not have been 0')
```

with:

```
 value++
```

With this solution you need to repeat the parsing operation whenever you deploy your application in production.